# What is "entityRef" element in qbXML with TimeActivity

Tags: qbxml

I am creating some time tracking software to interface with quickbooks, and below is my exported XML file. I receive status code 3140, saying there is an invalid reference to QuickBooks entity  in the TimeTracking. Quickbooks returns error : "The secified record does not exist in the list."

I have observed that if I pull out the EntityRef tag from the XML file, Quickbooks throws a parsing error, but I am at a total loss as to what needs to be inserted within the EntityRef element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
-<QBXML>
 -<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
  -<TimeTrackingAddRq>
   -<TimeTrackingAdd>
    -<EntityRef>
      <FullName>Some List Name Here?</FullName>
     </EntityRef>
     <Duration>PT8h5M</Duration>
    </TimeTrackingAdd>
   </TimeTrackingAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
 </QBXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

EntityRef/FullName can be either:

- an employee FullName
- a vendor FullName
- or an "Other Name" list FullName

i.e. it's the person/company that you're tracking time for.

In other requests, it can also be a customer FullName. But in the case of Time Tracking, it doesn't make sense to track time for a customer.

Quoting from the QuickBooks OSR documentation:

> *Entity* 
>   A QuickBooks "entity" is a customer, vendor, employee, or
>   person on the QuickBooks "other names" list.  Special cases to note: 
>   In a BillToPayQuery message, EntityRef refers to the vendor name. In
>   JournalCreditLine and JournalDebitLine messages for A/R accounts,
>   EntityRef must refer to a customer, or else the transaction will not
>   be recorded. For A/P accounts the EntityRef must refer to a vendor, or
>   else the transaction will not be recorded. In a TimeTracking message,
>   EntityRef cannot refer to a customer, only to an employee, vendor, or
>   person on the "other names" list whose time is being tracked.